# Network error(Request timeout) in Heroku Django app

Tags: python, django, heroku

I just started a new project and pushed it to heroku.

I set up everything: Procfile, dyno and environment variables.

Everything is working fine in localhost.

But I get `Network error` on browser and logs show me `Request timeout` and `Workder timeout` error in heroku.

I read that this happens when some request takes a lot of time. However, I don't have any request right now, it just shows `This is the landing page.`.

The only thing I have in my landing page is one css file which comes from AWS.

What could be a reason for this error?

**UPDATE:**

just found out that it is working in production only if `DEBUG` is set to `True`. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable in settings file.

I set it to `['appname.herokuapp.com']` and it is working fine now.